# Made a game with python and pygame. How can it be uploaded to the play store?

Tags: android, python, pygame

I made a game using pygame. I have it running and working as expected. But i can't seen to find a way to upload to the play store.

Comment: So do you need to convert it to an APK or you don't know how to put your APK on the google store?

Comment: Need to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be uploading the apk version of the code. With python it is not an easy task to do. Maybe you should give kivy a try.

[Kivy](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android)